# Django逆参照で子モデルから親の値にfilterを掛けて、データを取り出したい。

Tags: python, python3, django

現在Djangoのチュートリアルをしているのですが、下記のモデルで `views.py` で値を filterして取り出したいのですがどのようにコードを書いて良いか分かりません。詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか?

views.pyの `IndexView`の `return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` で Choiceモデルのchoice_textが1つもデータがないときに質問オブジェクトを返さないようにフィルターしたいです。どのように Questionモデルと結びつけられたChoiceモデルのデータにアクセスしたら良いのでしょうか?

そして `DetailView` も同様にURLが作成されないようにしたいです。 `return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())` に条件を追加したいです。

よろしくお願いします。

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
# 各モデルがmodels.Modelを継承して使っている。
# models.modelのサブクラスになる。
class Question(models.Model):
  # クラス変数を定義する。データベースフィールドを表現している。
  # Charフィールドは文字のフィールド
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  # 日時のフィールド
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

  def __str__(self):
    # インスタンスを生成して、printした際にここが実行される。
    # シェルで表示されるオブジェクトに質問名が使われるだけでなく
    # adminでオブジェクトを表現する際にも使用されるので追加する必要がある。
    return self.question_text
  
  def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    # now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)は今の時間から一日引いた日付を出す。
    # 2021-05-19 23:29:56.216634こんな感じの値になる。
    # pub_dateが現在時刻より過去で現在時刻から一日以内の場合はTrueを返すメソッド
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

class Choice(models.Model):

  # これはChoiceがQuestionに関連付けられている事を伝えている。
  # データベースの多対一、多対多、一対一のようなデータベースリレーションシップに対応する。
  # Question ← → Choiseと双方向のやりとりが可能となる。
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import context
from .models import Choice, Question
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    # テンプレート側でQuestion.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]を呼び出す際の名前を設定している。
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    # テンプレートで変数にアクセスする際はquestionになる。
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())



class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # resultsページのURLをreverseで取得してリダイレクトしている。引数としてquestion.idを渡している。
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    # /polls/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # ex：/polls/5/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

#### 追記

**polls:index**

[image: polls:index]

filterをかけてない状態だとtest3のような選択肢がない質問が一覧に表示されます。
それを取り除きたいです。

**test3**

[image: test3]

**what's up**

[image: what's up]

それで下記のようにviews.pyにfilterを追加したところ、test3は取り除けたのですが、なぜか一つしかない what's up の質問が2つ表示されるようになりました。

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    # テンプレート側でQuestion.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]を呼び出す際の名前を設定している。
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choice__choice_text__isnull=False).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

**編集後**

[image: 編集後]

Answer (score 1):

Choiceが少なくとも一つはあるQuestionだけを抽出したい、ということでいいでしょうか。(choice_textはNoneや空にはなりませんから)

次のようにするとそのようなQuestionを抽出できます。

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Question.objects.filter(
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
).filter(
    Exists(Choice.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk'))
)
```

**追記**
ご質問に追記の `.filter(choice__choice_text__isnull=False)` とする場合、同じ Question が質問の数だけ出てきますので、`.distinct()` をつけて重複を取り除く必要があります。

なぜそうなるかですが、この場合は実際には JOIN を行います。全ての Question と Choice の組み合わせのうち、Question と Choice が対応していて指定の条件を満たす組が全て抽出され、そこから Question だけを取り出すという感じになります。このため同じ Question が該当する Choice の数だけ出てきます。

Comment: すいません、伝わりづらくて一つもない奴を取り除きたいです。

Comment: 質問に追記しました。見て頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。